# How can i force my search input field to ignore non latin characters?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a search filter function for my website using jquery. It works pretty well with Latin characters but when i try to search for non  Latin characters like for example Swedish words it doesn't work.

This is the code i use:

```js
$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  if (valThis == "") {
    $('.navList > li').show();
  } else {
    $('.navList > li').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).show(): $(this).hide();
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Search Me" id="box" type="text" />
<ul class="navList">
  <li>människa</li>
  <li>träd</li>
  <li>acai</li>
  <li>blueberry</li>
  <li>bananas</li>
  <li>cherry</li>
  <li>coconut</li>
  <li>donut</li>
  <li>durean</li>
</ul>
```

Notice the 2 first words in the list are Swedish words. What i want to do is to make the search function to ignore the Swedish letters "ä" and treat them same with the Latin letter "a".

And just to make it more clear, i just want to force the search function to treat both letters "ä" and "a" as the same. So when you start typing... "ma" or "mä" to display the word "människa"

I have a live example here in [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q83f2/693/)

Comment: Looking at the fiddle, the search seems to work fine for me? (even with swedish letters). So to clearify, do you still want to "ignore" swedish letters? In that case, you could try using regular expressions.

Comment: Yes it works with Swedish letters but i want to still display the Swedish words no matter if i write "människa" or "manniska".

Comment: Do you have a full list of characters you would want to "convert"? This is probably pretty simple with a regex match.

Comment: Now the question becomes a lot clearer. So yeah, this can be done by using regular expressions for sure. I'd recommend you look up that and try to come up with a solution using that. In any case, you can come back to your question in case you need help with that.

Comment: @DBS i can give you an example of a full list of letters i would like to convert. For example i want to convert letters "'ά,έ,ή,ί,ό,ύ,ώ,ϊ,ϋ," to "α,ε,η,ι,ο,υ,ω,ι,υ"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the equivalent letters, then you can create a map for each letter to be replaced. I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scsiva1991/Q83f2/704/) please check.

```
var langMap = {
  'a': 'ä'
}

$('#box').keyup(function() {
  var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  var filteredWord = valThis.split('').map(function(letter) {
    if (langMap[letter]) {
      return langMap[letter];
    }
    return letter;
  }).join('');

  if (filteredWord == "") {
    $('.navList > li').show();
  } else {
    $('.navList > li').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      (text.indexOf(filteredWord) >= 0) ? $(this).show(): $(this).hide();
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: just one more question. How can i include more letters inside the langMap variable ?

Comment: You can add multiple letters like {'a':'ä', 'b':'b'}

Comment: Ι already tried that but didn't work. Also if you check the updated http://jsfiddle.net/d3s1gn3r/sdj96mcf/25/ you will notice that if you type the first word which is Greek "Πορτοκάλια" if the word is completed then the result is not displaying. If you delete the last letter then the result is displaying. One more issue is that if there are more than 2 words that contain the letter "ά" then the filter function works only for the first one !!

Comment: You have mapped a letter {'α' : 'ά'}, but in the option list you have Πορτοκάλια so it didn't pick the word. If the option is Πορτοκάλιά then it will work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#box').keyup(function() {
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#box').val(valThis.replace(/[\u0250-\ue007]/g, '')); //non-latin letter will be removed. 
    if (valThis == "") {
        $('.navList > li').show();
    } else {
        $('.navList > li').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).show(): $(this).hide();
        });
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Search Me" id="box" type="text" />
<ul class="navList">
   <li>människa</li>
   <li>träd</li>
   <li>acai</li>
   <li>blueberry</li>
   <li>bananas</li>
   <li>cherry</li>
   <li>coconut</li>
   <li>donut</li>
   <li>durean</li>
</ul>
```

Explanation:- I tried by using **مرحبا** letters and it is working form me

Comment: I dont want to remove or replace the letters. I just want force the search function to treat both letters "ä" and "a" as the same. So when you start typing... "ma" or "mä" to display the word "människa" .