# Search filter function with non Latin characters using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Based on a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52002922/how-can-i-force-my-search-input-field-to-ignore-non-latin-characters/52004614) of mine i am trying to build - with the help of the community - a search filter function that works even when the user types non Latin characters in the search input field (in this case Swedish letters).

This is what i have until now:

```js
var langMap = {
'a' : 'å',
'a' : 'ä',
'o' : 'ö'
}

$('#search-items-box').keyup(function(){
   var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
   var filteredWord = valThis.split('').map(function(letter){
    if (langMap[letter]) {
     return langMap[letter];
    }
    return letter;
   }).join('');
   
    if(filteredWord == ""){
        $('.itemsList .m3-item').show();           
    } else {
        $('.itemsList .m3-item').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            (text.indexOf(filteredWord) == 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
        });
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Search Me" id="search-items-box" type="text" /> 

<div class="itemsList">
<div class="m3-item">Orånge</div>
<div class="m3-item">Banäna</div>
<div class="m3-item">Potatö</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the search doesn't work properly. If you try to type the three words you will notice that the results doesn't display.

[JSFIDDLE Here](http://jsfiddle.net/d3s1gn3r/sdj96mcf/35/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first condition is altering the character input at every key stroke if the condition is satisfied:

```
if (langMap[letter]) {
    return langMap[letter];
```

Now, when you type in 'b', Banana appears in the search because 'b' is not part of your langMap array and hence, it is not modified. It searches for any word starting with 'b' and the search result is 'Banäna'

However, once you type 'a', Banana is no longer there because it was transformed into 'å'. As a result, it is searching for 'bå' which returns zero results (as expected).

On another note, you may also encounter another problem later on with your langMap array:

```
var langMap = {
    'a' : 'å',
    'a' : 'ä',
    'o' : 'ö'
};
```

You have one key, `'a'`, which defines two different values. One of the values will never be accessible.

**Based on our discussion, here is my proposed solution:**

- Invert the keys and values for the `langMap`
- Transform the compared text into latin characters

  ```
   var langMap = {
    "å":"a",
    "ä":"a",
    "ö":"o"
   }

   $('#search-items-box').keyup(function(){
    var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var filteredWord = getLatinWord(valThis);

    if(filteredWord == ""){
        $('.itemsList .m3-item').show();           
    } else {
        $('.itemsList .m3-item').each(function(){
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            text = getLatinWord(text);
            (text.indexOf(filteredWord) === 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
        });
    }
   });

   function getLatinWord(word){
     return word.split('').map(function(character){
                            if (langMap[character]) {
                              return langMap[character];
                            }
                            return character;
                         }).join('');
   }
  ```

Comment: So what would be a solution here? I guess there must be a function that treats  letter "a" as equal to "å"  & "ä" and vice versa. This way the filter function will work without problems.

Comment: Just to clarify, the user isn't typing 'a' into the search right? You are trying to support the scenario in which the user types in a non-latin character. So I think the langMap would still work as long as you switch the position keys and values. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Nope. There is the possibility that user will type "a" or "å", or even "ä" No matter what he/she types i want the result to be "Banäna" For example if i type "Banana" the result must display "Banäna". If i type "Banäna" the result must be again "Banäna" and so on for all other letters.

Comment: So if there is the word Banana and Banäna, do you want both to appear if they type Banana.

Comment: Yes exactly, and vice versa. If there are the words "Banana and Banäna" and they type "Banäna" or/and "Banana" i want both to appear "Banana and Banäna".

Comment: Okay sure thing! I think I have a solution. Let me test it out :)

Comment: I have added my solution, please let me know if it works out!

Comment: WOW! Amazing work. Thank you so much for your effort @Apogee. I just checked it and worked perfect. Just one little notice. How we can also keep it working and display results when someone types the letters mixed up ? For example is it possible if someone types "nge" to get as result the word "Orånge" ??? Or if someone types the word "Ornge" still get the result "Orånge" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178733/discussion-between-designer-and-apogee).

Answer (score 0):

Here I propose a more data-centric approach. It is a question of normalizing your possible matches to your needs. According to your specification a normalized word should have the following characteristics:

1. Replace all non ASCII characters with their ASCII approximation
2. Everything should be lowercase

This is done in the function `normalizeWord`.

The rest of the code creates a `dictionary` that binds the original
word to it's normalized representation. The `filter` function returns
a list of the original words from your dataset, that are matched to the input.

Actually there is a little mismatch in binding the code to the DOM because this approach actually works on a given dataset. In real life I would just rebuild the HTML representation of the matches from the filtered list instead of showing and hiding already existing DOM elements.

```
$(function() {
  var langMap = {
    'å' : 'a',
    'ä' : 'a',
    'ö' : 'o'
  };

  var words = [
    'Orånge',
    'Banäna',
    'Potatö'
  ];

  // Create normalized words

  // The map with the original and normalized word
  var dictionary = {};

  // Normalization
  words.forEach(function(w) {
    var word = normalizeWord(w);
    dictionary[word] = w;
  });

  function normalizeWord(word) {
    for (key in langMap) {
      word = word.toLowerCase()
        .replace(new RegExp(key, 'g'), langMap[key]);
    }
    return word;
  }

  function filter(word) {
    var possibleMatch = normalizeWord(word);
    var result = [];
    for (normalizedWord in dictionary) {
      if (normalizedWord.indexOf(possibleMatch) === 0) {
        result.push(dictionary[normalizedWord]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  // Test
  var results = [
    'b -> ' + filter('b'),
    'bs -> ' +  filter('bs'),
    'baNana -> ' + filter('baNana'),
    'Potatö ->  ' + filter('Potatö')
  ]

  console.log(results);

  // Binding to the DOM
  $('#search-items-box').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var matches = filter(value);

    if (matches.length === 0) {
      $('.itemsList .m3-item').show();
      return;
    }

    $('.itemsList .m3-item').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        value = $this.html();

      if (matches.indexOf(value) > -1) {
        $this.show();
      } else {
        $this.hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```